# SQL Delete with 1 to 1 relation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys

My database is MySQL with foreign key management. It has 2 tables :

```
Table1 :
|id|foreignKeyToTable2|data...|

Table2 : 
|id|foreignKeyToTable1|data...|
```

I want to delete a couple of these lines but when I delete one of them I have the meaningful foreign key error.

How can I delete the couple of lines in one time?

Am I forced to disable foreign key checks?

### Edit : Problem with delete cascade

I need both of the keys because there is actually 2 relations. Lets be more practical :

- the table 1 is a "drop down list" that has a default value.
- the table 2 has every values possible for each DDL in table 1.

Tables are :

```
DDL
|id|name|defaultValue (FK delete cascade)|
Value
|id|name|DDLiD (FK)|
```

Following your answers, I added a DELETE CASCADE to the DDL table. But I still have a FK error .

Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (Value, CONSTRAINT fk_Value_DDL FOREIGN KEY (DDL) REFERENCES DDL (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

I don't want to add a delete cascade on the Value table because i want to be able to delete a value.

Comment: You've created a cyclic dependency. This should never be done or avoided. Is there any specific business reason for such a table structure? Usually the relationship should be kept unidirectional; that is., table-1 with FK relation with Table-2 or a Table-3 with FK references from both table-1 and table-2 and then probably a composite key constraint (if required).

Comment: @TathagatVerma I edited my post to show you my business reason. Do you see another way to model the DDL with values and default value ?

Comment: @NicolasThery: Please refer my answer..

Comment: @NicolasThery: I mentioned so, only if you wanted to keep data-references of both tables in each-other, as it was shown in your post. Please refer my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Alter the foreign key definition to also delete referenced rows.
   This can be done with [`ON DELETE CASCADE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).
2. Use a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html) around the two delete statements.

The second option is my prefered one, because a database user is informed about the usage in the other table and can then decide to use a transaction to remove data from both rows.

Also, one usage scenario of a 1:1 relation is to allow different permissions on both tables. When using delete cascade I don't know if these are checked.

**EDIT**

After I was pointed that MySQL is handling foreign key checking not as stated in the SQL standards, my second option is changed to:

2.
Because MySQL does not support [deferred checking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html) of foreign key constraints while using transactions (this is a deviation from SQL standards), you need to disable foreign key checks for the delete statements:

```
    SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
    DELETE ...;
    SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, I like the transaction solution, I try it and tell you if its ok

Comment: Sorry, transaction does not work, I still have the foreign key error.

Comment: Ups, this is strange. I thought MySQL is becoming a real database engine, but this changes my view. I'm sorry for this. FYI the five year old [bug report on this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10754). Therefore, I recommend to disable foreign key checks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the foreign key to cascade mode:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  fields....
  FOREIGN KEY fk_name(fk_to_table2) REFERENCES table2.id  
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE   <<--- Change this.
```

If you change the table layout like this, MySQL will not block, but instead propagate the deletion.

Note that if you have a 1-to-1 relation, you do not have a separate foreign key field, but your primary key links to another primary key, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  id UNSIGNED INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  otherfields....,
) ENGINE = InnoDB;  <<-- no foreign key in T1, because t1 is the master.


CREATE TABLE t2 (
  id UNSIGNED INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  otherfields....,
  FOREIGN KEY fk_t1_id(id) REFERENCES t1(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE = InnoDB;  <<-- t2 follows t1.
```

Now you enforce a 1-1 relationship, instead of a 1-n.

Note that setting `NO ACTION` is the same as `RESTRICT`:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

> NO ACTION: A keyword from standard SQL. In MySQL, equivalent to RESTRICT. InnoDB rejects the delete or update operation for the parent table if there is a related foreign key value in the referenced table. Some database systems have deferred checks, and NO ACTION is a deferred check. In MySQL, foreign key constraints are checked immediately, so NO ACTION is the same as RESTRICT.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Actually I need to have both foreign keys. See my answer.

Comment: @NicolasThery, that does not make sense, but if it's like that, then you need **not set a foreign key at all**.

Answer (score 1):

Using a cascade delete / update should handle the necessary.

I've got an alternative suggestion though, which is more of an architectural solvent/resolve.

- By design: rather than deleting data, always deactivate it
- You could keep a column: `Status | BIT | Default(1)`
- This column may or may not be present in the secondary table
- By code-design all you've got to handle is, when you get (all SELECT queries) secondary data always put the condition: `PrimaryTable.Status = 1` when joining with the primary table
- Doing so will eliminate the need to apply constraints on the primary-table design

Answer (score 0):

Use `on delete cascade` while creating your table

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to remove one of the foreign keys and manage it with the application.
tables are now :

```
DDL
|id|name|defaultValue|
Value
|id|name|DDLiD (FK)|
```

defaultValue is an id of the table Value but not a foreign key...

When I want to delete, first I delete the values, then I delete the DDL.

Thank you all.

Nicolas.

Answer (score 0):

lets assume we have two tables
foo has **Id | Name | carId**

bar has **Id | Color**

to delete both tables

```
delete bar where id in (select f.Id from foo f inner join boo b on b.Id = f.Id where f.carId = 22)
```